# What means }; in Java code

Tags: java

I found this piece of code:

```
public static class SinTransform implements ITransform{
    public double transform(double value){
        return sin(value);
        };
}
```

and I would like to know what `;` after `}` means? When I need to wrote it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means empty statement which is *terminated* by `;`, it says there is nothing but still *empty* to compute. Following is a valid java class.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ;
        ;
        ;
        ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not only empty but also ends the statement.

Comment: Technically I don't think it is an empty statement. You can't have statements outside methods/constructors/initialisers.